# Adding navigation drawer to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, navigation-drawer

I need to add a navigation drawer to my app. The activities extend AppCompatActivity. I want the navigation drawer to be used in some of the activities. The navigation drawer should look something like the one if the play store (i.e. a circled ImageView and some text + a listView). Can I edit the code available when creating a new navigation drawer activity in Android studio?

I tried the following code [Here](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html) and extended it in my activity but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes using the navigation drawer template activity is a complete mess. Try this [tutorial](http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/). Slidenerd is a really good source for the new material design stuff. :)

Comment: This tutorial is great, thank you, but when the navigation drawer is opened, it covers the toolbar icon. How can we fix that? And how can we add the same navigation drawer to another activity?

Comment: No problem. Thats a good question, however the navigation drawer [material spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#) states that it should in fact lay over the toolbar, but I'm sure theres a workaround in case you wanted to design it to slide out under. To answer your second question, what you can actually do is rather then creating a brand new activity with a brand new navigation bar, just use the same navigation bar (and elements within) to switch fragments that will appear in the frame layout. I hope this helps to answer your question @MotassemJa

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreaciate it.

Comment: No problem :D Good luck!